# Implement Country Flag dropdown and get area code on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, phone-number

I need a control in which flags will be populated and selecting the same will give the area code in ReactJs . Need to keep the flag dropdown , areacode label and textbox for phone number separate .

I have tried many packages like React-Phone-Input-2, React-telephone-input but it is wrapped to be on control which cannot be customized .

Comment: I suggest if you don't need the complex functionality then go ahead and create a one for your own purpose.